# Will new Facebook Login affect ACAccountStore

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-login, acaccount, acaccountstore

In Facebook's [New Login and Graph API 2.0 announcement](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2014/04/30/the-new-facebook-login/) they detail all the changes coming to Login, like allowing a user to opt out of sharing specific personal information like email, birthday, and friend list.

I don't use the FB SDK in my iOS app, but instead rely on `ACAccountStore` to log my users in. If a user is signing up with my app using Facebook, I need their email address and can't create an account if they specifically decline that permission.

I can't find any documentation or references to if/how these changes will apply to `ACAccountStore`.
Using `ACAccountStore`, does anybody have any information on whether or not we'll be subject to the new login flow as well?